# Linking Bonjour SDK's dnssd.lib using MinGW gives SEGV

Tags: mingw, bonjour

I am trying to integrate Bonjour with my Windows application using MinGW. I have downloaded the latest Bonjour SDK for Windows 2.0.4 and linked the dnssd.lib. The compilation, linking goes fine but I get a weird SIGSEGV with no stack trace. Thanks in advance for any help or suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue using the dll and loading it as required through Qt class QLibrary.

Comment: where found the dll file?

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to link statically? You can't mix MinGW and MSVC static libraries but you can link dynamically.

Comment: I only have the .lib file shipped with the SDK. I am not sure if there are any .dll files to link dynamically with. Let me know if I am missing something here. I am just linking the dnssd.lib through -ldnssd. Please let me know if I need to do it some other way. Thanks again.

Comment: I am not getting any linking error. The compilation and linking goes fine (I am using Qt Creator). But when I am running the application it gives a segv. While debugging with Qt Creator it shows the following stack trace.